# Unrecognized token error when declaring a cudaError_t variable

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new to Cuda and just started writing a simple program to test it. There are probably a lot of issues in it, but the stopper for me right now is the error I described in the title : whenever I declare a simple cudaError_t variable, I get an "Unrecognized token" compile error.
Here is my code sample :

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

extern "C" void callCudaCode(int*);

__global__ void mykernel (int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    //*c = *a + *b;
    *c = 34;
}


void callCudaCode(int* results)
{
    int a=3, b=8;
    int *da, *db, *dc;
    int size = sizeof(int);

    ​cudaError_t myCudaError;// = cudaGetLastError();
    //const char* errorStr = cudaGetErrorName(cudaError);

    cudaMalloc((void**)da, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)db, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)dc, size);

    cudaMemcpy(da, &a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(db, &b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    mykernel<<<1,1>>>(da,db,dc);

    cudaMemcpy(results, dc, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(da);
    cudaFree(db);
    cudaFree(dc);
}
```

There is another main.cpp file that uses this files but I don't think it has anything relevant to explain this error, so I didn't include it.
If I comment the cudaError_t variable declaration, the code compiles fine (It doesn't execute fine, but that's another story).

I've already googled this issue but only found errors that don't have anything to do with my example : space errors, printf errors...

From what I understand, cudaError_t is an enum that is defined in cuda_runtime_api.h, so by including it I shouldn't have any problem...

Does anyone have any clue on what is going on?

**EDIT**

The file I just attached is mycuda.cu. There is another file named main.cpp that just calls the callCudaCode() function from mycuda.cu.
I am using Qt Creator and qmake to build the project. Yes, I took care to configure the .pro file so that Qt does not try to compile the .cu project.
If I comment the line declaring myCudaError variable, the project compiles fine. If I uncomment it, I get the compilation issue.

Comment: What is the name of the file in question - Are you using a filename that ends in `.cpp` by any chance?

Comment: This file is cuda.cu. There is another main.cpp that just calls callCudaCode() from this file.

Comment: If the file has a `.cu` extension then CUDA runtime includes are unnecessary - nvcc will automatically include the CUDA headers.

Comment: In order to make sure I am not interfering somehow with the internal cuda mechanics, I just renamed the file to mycuda.cu.
Ok, the includes are unnecessary, I just removed them and the behaviour did not change. However, this did not solve the issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
    ​cudaError_t myCudaError;// = cudaGetLastError();
```

appears to have a Unicode 0x200B "zero-width space" character before `cudaError_t`. Delete it (or delete and retype the entire line if unsure) and try again.

Comment: Same for me. I copied "cudaError_t" from the NVIDIA reference website, so I guess the zero-width space came from there.

Answer (score 5):

`cudaError` is a reserved CUDA keyword.

Don't use that as a variable name.

Change it to something like:

```
cudaError_t my_cudaError;
```

(`cudaError` is already defined in `driver_types.h`.  It is an enum type.)

Comment: Thank you Robert for your answer, I wasn't aware of that. I just renamed the variable to myCudaError but the issue still remains.
Any other idea?

By the way, I am using QtCreator and qmake to build the project. As it builds without the variable declaration line, I suppose this won't help, but if someone feels this might help diagnosing the error, please just tell me and I'll put it.

Comment: Just as CUDA does, QT also introduces it's own preprocessing steps which in my (limited) experience are incompatible with CUDA. So best make sure that QT only handles `.cpp` files, and that all CUDA code is limited to `.cu` files.

Comment: Already did that. It QT were to handle the .cu file, there would be plenty of compilation errors (which were present before I resolved this issue).